# What are the differences between an elementCriteriaModel and fetched elements?

Tags: entries, elementcriteriamodel

I am a little confused about the differences between an [elementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) and fetched elements.

Why do I sometimes have to fetch elements with [`first()`, `last()`, `find()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#outputting-elements):

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('cocktails').find() %}
```

and in other cases the [elementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) is enough:

```
{% set params = craft.entries.section('cocktails') %}
{% set prev   = entry.getPrev(params) %}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `ElementCriteriaModel` and the individual element models (like the `EntryModel`) can be thought of as two different points of time in retrieving data from your database. Essentially, you'll use an `ElementCriteriaModel` before the database is queried and the element models afterwards.

> Why do I sometimes have to fetch elements with `.first()`, `.last()`, `.find()`…

The `ElementCriteriaModel` does what it says on the tin — it specifies criteria to find elements. When you call `.find()`, `.first()` or `.last()`, the model sends itself off to the `ElementsService` which will return element models, based on your criteria.

> …and in other cases the ElementCriteriaModel is enough?

Internally, Craft is using `ElementCriteriaModels` to work things out. For pagination or the `.getPrev()` example, Craft is finding elements using the same criteria, but it's using it in a different way to `.find()` or similar methods.

You *can* omit the `.find()` method and treat the `ElementCriteriaModel` as an array, but it depends on your scenario. As was touched on [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/59/what-are-the-most-common-template-performance-gotchas-to-avoid/), there are performance impacts to consider.

Comment: Definitely a better answer...I'm voting for yours!

Comment: Elegant and succinct. Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> Treating your ElementCriteriaModel object as an array will get it to act like one, too. (No find() necessary!)

See the fourth point [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#outputting-elements).

Comment: But in what cases do I need the model and in what the fetched elements? For example pagination needs the model. -- And if it gets added automatically does that mean that I never need to add .find() ? (Assuming I don't pass parameters in it)

Comment: I'm not completely sure of all the different cases but I know that when using `relatedTo()` you can just give it the model. I think most of the times you can actually do both, maybe pagination is a one off here (@bradbell or @brandonkelly will know more). Its certainly worth playing with in various cases though as in one example I found using `.ids()` over just the model was a significant performance increase.