# Paginate An Array Of Entries

Tags: pagination

I have read through the [docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/tags#paginate) and I am not sure if what I need to do is possible with array sets. I have filtered my entries using the following code"

```twig
{% set allDatabytes = craft.entries.section('databytes').limit(null) %}
{% set seriesCollection = [] %}

{% for databyte in allDatabytes %}

  {# get only the series databytes #}
  {% set series = databyte.series %}

  {# add the series databytes to the series collection #}
  {% for entry in series %}
    {% set seriesCollection = seriesCollection|merge([entry.title]) %}
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}

{# Output the filtered results #}

{% set filteredDatabytes = allDatabytes|without(seriesCollection) %}
<ul>
  {% for entry in filteredDatabytes %}
    <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

What I now need to do is add pagination to the `filteredDatabytes` set of content.

**From The Example Below**

This is my code which currently doesn't display any results. I guess you add the limit to the `MyCriteria` model (is that the correct term)?

```twig
{% set MyCriteria = craft.entries.section('databytes').series(':empty:').limit(10) %}

{% paginate MyCriteria as entries %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if paginate.prevUrl %}
        <a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}">Previous Page</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if paginate.nextUrl %}
        <a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}">Next Page</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Victor rightfully points out](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/782/57), the {% paginate %} tags require an ElementCriteriaModel, so you can't do what you're doing in your first example because as soon as you call:

```
{% for databyte in allDatabytes %}
```

Craft hits the database and converts the ElementCriteriaModel into actual EntryModels.

We also don't have support, yet, for passing `:empty:` into things like AssetFields, TagFields, etc., which is why your second example won't work...  however that is on our list to add!

In this case, I think your best bet is going to be to do through the search service with something like this:

```
{# Search for 10 entries in the 'databytes' section where the 'series' assetField doesn't have anything selected. #}
{% set myCriteria = craft.entries.section('databytes').search('-series:*').limit(10) %}

{% paginate myCriteria as entries %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if paginate.prevUrl %}
        <a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}">Previous Page</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if paginate.nextUrl %}
        <a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}">Next Page</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

Comment: Hi Brad, thank you that worked great. Its good to see there is so many different ways to attack a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work with your example, because the [pagination-tag](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/tags#paginate) only accepts an [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel), not an array of already fetched entries:

```twig
{% paginate MyCriteria as PageSubset %}
```

See also: [What are the differences between an elementCriteriaModel and fetched elements?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/265/177)

---

If I understand your code correctly, you want to get all entries which have an empty `series`-field?

If so, you don't have to fetch all entries and check against it, you can just add this to the [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel):

```twig
{% set MyCriteria = craft.entries.section('databytes').series(':empty:') %}

{% paginate MyCriteria as entries %}
....
{% endpaginate %}
```

---

**Why does the pagination tag need a CriteriaModel?**

An ElementCriteriaModel can be compared to a sql query, it specifies what elements/entries to fetch (it sets the criteria). If you [treat your CriteriaModel as an array or append .first()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#outputting-elements) it will fetch those entries and replace the results with the CriteriaModel.

The [pagination-tag](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/tags#paginate) needs a CriteriaModel (or "query") because it adds an offset (to the "query") depending on what page you are on, and then fetches the entries. - That's why the pagination-tag doesn't work with already fetched entries.

Comment: Hi Victor, thank you, that looks like just the solution I am after. I spent ages trying to figure out what I came up with to. Sorry but how Craft works with ElementCriteriaModels is till very confusing to me and I have read the docs and Stuarts post a few times. Could you expand on your example as the only pagination example I have is http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/tags#paginate and I can't figure what to add to your solution to make it work. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I added an explanation for the CriteriaModel. Copying the example pagination-code from the docs inside my example should work fine, what problems do you have exactly?

Comment: Hi Victor, thank you for the explanation and I have updated my example to show you what I have which currently displays no results.

Comment: I tested your code and it worked in my test. What field type is `series` and what does it contain?

Comment: `series` is an entries field type: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields and can contain multiple related entries.

Comment: Can you remove `.series(':empty:')` to check if all entries are fetched. If so, can you make sure that there is an entry where the `series` field is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15587/discussion-between-gareth-redfern-and-victor-in).