# Refer to specific section handle when querying an element by 'getCriteria'

Tags: plugin-development

I can do the following to pull out the page title after parsing in just the page slug:

```
$page = 'about';
$entry = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry)->first();
$entry->slug = $page;
echo $entry->title;
```

(I understand this is overkill, but an answer to this question will help me answer further questions I dare not try to explain here).

The problem is, the slug doesn't need to be unique if other sections/channels/singles use the same name, and the method above only calls out the first instance of "about".

**How can I define what section is being referred to?**

This will update the handle, but has no effect on the output:

```
$entry->section->handle = "pages";
```

This returns a Read Only error:

```
$entry->section = "Pages"
```

> Property "Craft\EntryModel.section" is read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of incorrect things going on in your current example.

Calling `craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry)` returns an [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel).

That's what you want to set the parameters on for the entries you're searching for. Stuart sums it up well [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-are-the-differences-between-an-elementcriteriamodel-and-fetched-elements).

By calling `->first()` on it immediately, you're going to get the defaults, which for entries is by post date in descending order.

By calling:

```
$entry->slug = $page;
echo $entry->title;
```

You are actually updating the slug for the entry that was returned to be something new.

This should work for what you're trying to do:

```
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->slug = 'about';
    $criteria->section = 'news';
    $entry = $criteria->first();
    $title = $entry->title;
```

Comment: Thanks Brad [again]. I realised calling ->first() was the start of my problems, I realise now I overlooked some fairly basic formatting/syntax issues too. Works like a charm.