# Optimizing pagespeed

Tags: speed, optimization, query

I'm not sure what is the cause for this page rendering so slow.
I thought it was the image transforms but I've removed them and still it's really slow to render.

Page in question: http://dharmaavenue.net/e-drops

From the profiling report:

Time:   64.61081s

Memory: 461,289Kb

Total Queries: 52

As you can see it's just a simple nav menu.
Here is the code:

```
{% block content %}

    {% set eDrops = craft.entries.section('eDrops') %}

    <nav id="linksBrowser" class= "ladder tree">
        <ul>
            {% nav entry in eDrops %}
                <li>
                    {% if entry.slides|length %}
{#
                        {% set image = entry.slides.first() %}
#}
                        <a href="{{ entry.url }}"> {{ entry.title }} >

{#
                        <img src="{{ image.getUrl('fitThumb') }}"
                                width= "{{ image.getWidth('fitThumb') }}"
                                height= "{{ image.getHeight('fitThumb') }}"/>
#}
                        </a>

                    {% else %}
                        <span class="linkAnchor">{{ entry.title }}</span>
                    {% endif %}

                    {% ifchildren %}
                        <ul>
                            {% children %}
                        </ul>
                    {% endifchildren %}

                </li>
            {% endnav %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
{% endblock %}
```

The entries are basically individual gallerys with many images in the slides field. I'm guessing that all the details of these are being fetched unecessarily, and that stopping this from happenign will solve my problem.

If anyone can help me with this it would be most greatful :)

Comment: BTW. I took the cache tags out and commented the images for debugging to try find the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you implemented the `cache` tags, but I would recommend to cache each "eDrops" entry individually.

I also took out `{% if entry.slides|length %}`. Testing if `entry.slides.first()` returns anything is all you need. In order to make the length filter work, Craft internally applys `find()` to the criteria model behind `entry.slides`. This means you (unintentionally) added an additional database query (besides `first()`, which you need anyways).

Keep in mind, that assets are elements in Craft and relationship queries take their time (→ also explained in the Matrix field example here: [What are the most common template performance gotchas to avoid?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/59/125)).

```
{% nav entry in eDrops %}

    {% cache globally using key 'eDrops-' ~ entry.id %}
        {% set image = entry.slides.first() %}

        {% if image %}
            <img src="{{ image.getUrl('fitThumb') }}">
        {% else %}
            {{ entry.title }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endcache %}

    {% ifchildren %}
        {% children %}
    {% endifchildren %}

{% endnav %}
```

Comment: Amazing ! 
Without the cache: 
Time:   0.68351s
Memory: 17,065Kb
Total Queries: 51

Comment: that's the same comparison with the image commented out...
with it in:
Time:   1.59595s
Memory: 18,967Kb
Total Queries: 155

Comment: Wooot? Can you still cache it and tell us the time?

Comment: Caching the whole nav section Time:   0.14703s
Memory: 8,775Kb
Total Queries: 12

and caching as you recommended:
Time:   0.61642s
Memory: 11,633Kb
Total Queries: 50

Comment: I'm amazed at how much overhead the |length requires !

Comment: Well, you could do both, individual entries and the complete list. So you're not totally uncached after invalidation. But the gains are marginally in this case.

Comment: *"how much overhead the |length requires"* – you to give us an impression, are there many assets on the average entry?

Comment: indeed there are 100s of hi-res images on each one.... I thought that entry.slides|length would just return the length of the array ie. number of assets... which would be low computation cost compared to whatever it is doing!

Comment: If you would need to know the number, you could request the IDs: `entry.slides.ids()|length`.